# How to show Json data to the dialog box in html

Tags: html, mysql, ajax, json, datatable

I am a beginner in the ajax, dom, jsonm etc in web application. my project is to use jquery UI to parse json data and show all of data from database and retrive one data by id, it's part of create, retrieve, update, and delete. so retrieving is key function here. I can get all data and populate datatable with all data no problem.

```
      "aoColumns" :[          
                    {"mData" : "image"},
                    {"mData" : "name"},
                    {"mData" : "type"},
                    {"mData" : "description"},
                    {"mData" : "price"},
                    {"mData" : "id",                       
                     "mRender" : function(data, type,full)
                                                  {return '<a href="#" id="'+ full.id +
                                                 '" class="id">Details</a>'; }
                     }
```

-->to fetch all the data

```
var findById= function(id) { 
 console.log('findById: ' + id); 
  $.ajax({ 
       type:'GET', 
       url: rootUrl + '/' + id, 
       dataType: "json", 
       success: renderList
});
};   


var renderList = function(data){

           var list = data == null?[] : (data instanceof Array ? data : [ data ]);

            ///////////////////////////////////     
              solution1//////////////////////////////////////////////////
          $.each(list, function(index, pet){
              var row="<tr>" + "<td>" + pet.type + "</td>" 
                             + "<td>" + pet.price + "</td>" 
                             + "<td>" + pet.contact_no+ "</td>" 
                             + "<td> "+ pet.contact + "</td>" 
                     + "</tr>";
              //$(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
              $(row).appendTo('dialogTable tbody');
            });
```

to retrieve more details

the result(in xml) show this if I click  the "details " link by checking element,

```
<pet>
<contact>bob.hoskins@lgfriday.com</contact>
<contact_no>5-(254)756-8567</contact_no>
<description>Great companion for up to 75 years</description>
<id>42</id>
<image>bird</image>
<name>Amazon</name>
<price>40</price>
<type>BIRDS</type>
</pet>
```

(failed)
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

the data is coming back in MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML so I can check data type easily but cant make connection to it to show in dialog box

```
<div id="dialog" title="More Information">
        <table id="dialogTable" style="width: 350px;">
            <thead>
                <tr id="findById">


                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: What errors gives you? can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I had set `var rooturl = http://localhost/xxx/rest/xxx";` instead of rooturl = `"http://localhost:8080/xxx/rest/xxx"` . It solved the cross origin connection and connection failure problem and now it renders.